# Unable to a declare a table in flask model which has dates in it

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am creating a Flask Based Web App.
It has 2 types of users: BBank and Standard User

I want a Standard User to be able to send a request from its dashboard to BBank's dashboard. And BBank should approve or disaprove that request. AND same should go the other way round (BBank if wants a donation it should send a request to Standard User)

Steps implemented:

Created a Table with all the required details (receive_by, receive_date, etc).
I just want date not date and time

--models.py--

```py
from .database import db
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import func, text
from datetime import datetime

class DonationRequests(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'donationrequests'
    Req_id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement = True, primary_key = True, nullable = False)
    Received_date = db.Column(db.Date, default=db.func.today(), nullable=False)  # i think this line is causing an error
    Received_from = db.Column(db.Text, db.ForeignKey('Users.username', ondelete = 'CASCADE'), nullable = False)
    Req_status = db.Column(db.Text, default = 'pending')
    Received_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Bloodbank.bank_id', ondelete = 'CASCADE', nullable = False))
    Response_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable = True)
    rejected_msg = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = True)
```

system_default and text was used on ChatGPT's suggestion, but the problem persisted

ERROR ENCOUNTERED:

> line 40, in 
> class DonationRequests(db.Model):

TypeError: Additional arguments should be named < dialectname >_< argument>, got 'nullable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nullable](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.nullable) is an argument to [Column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column). If you pass it to a type constructor, like `ForeignKey` which inherits from [DialectKWArgs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/foundation.html#sqlalchemy.sql.base.DialectKWArgs), then SQLAlchemy assumes that you are trying to pass a dialect-specific argument to the type constructor, hence the error message.

The line should be

```py
...
    Received_by = db.Column(
                      db.Integer,
                      db.ForeignKey('Bloodbank.bank_id', ondelete = 'CASCADE'),
                      nullable = False
    )
```

Comment: Thank You So much @snakecharmerb!! I have spent like 5hrs on this thing, even used ChatGPT for this but it turned out to be futile. 
Thanks a ton.

Comment: Don't trust ChatGPT.